# JSplitPane Components Not Focusing

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jsplitpane

I am encountering a problem where I have a `JSplitPane` with two components, the left is a `JPanel` and the right is a second `JSplitPane` containing `JTextArea`'s.

The issue is, my program starts out focusing the top of the second `JSplitPane` (As intended), however when I click on the `JPanel`, it does not focus, therefore any key I press to activate Key listeners I have added to the `JPanel` is responded to by the `JTextArea` (Usually by writing a letter).

Answer (score 3):

KeyEvents are only generated for the component with focus. A JPanel is not focusable by default. You could make the panel focusable.

However a better solution is to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which can work even when the panel doesn't have focus. `Key Bindings` are a newer API and Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings.